# Reversing a Range results in Mismatching Types

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, iterable, type-mismatch

I want to use a variable to hold what would normally be a range of something, for example `Range<Int>`, so that I can use conditional logic to change the range of a loop without copy/pasting the for loop. For instance:

```
let range = aNumber % 2 == 0 ? 0..<10 : (0..<10).reverse()
for i in range { /* for loop logic */ }
```

The line `let range = ...` will result in the error:  `Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'Range<Int>' and 'ReverseRandomAccessCollection<Range(Int)'`. I would've guessed that reversing the range would result in the same type of range or at least a protocol or something that both values inherit/implement so I could declare `let range: SomeType = ...`. I have not been able to find that though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`AnySequence`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_AnySequence_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/struct/s:VSs11AnySequence) to create a "type-erased sequence"
which forwards the operations to the underlying sequence, hiding the specifics of the underlying `SequenceType`:

```
let range = aNumber % 2 == 0
            ? AnySequence ( (0 ..< 10) )
            : AnySequence ( (0 ..< 10).reverse() )

for i in range { print(i) }
```

Both expression in the ternary conditional operator have the
same type `AnySequence<Int>`, so that is the type of `range`.

For Swift 3 and later, replace `reverse()` by `reversed()`.